# Use regular expression to find HTML tags in MySQL post_content column and replace with cleaned result

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bash

Database table contains numerous instances of malicious scripts wrapped in `</noindex>` tags. In need of command or script that will use regex to find the code and replace them with empty strings.

I have a MySQL function that performs a regex_replace find and replace loop. Function code is included below. I reference the function using the UPDATE command below the function. I need to find all of the instances of the `<noindex></noindex>` code and replace it and everything inside of it with an empty string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION  `regex_replace`(pattern VARCHAR(1000),replacement VARCHAR(1000),original VARCHAR(1000))

RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
 DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000); 
 DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1); 
 DECLARE i INT;
 SET i = 1;
 SET temp = '';
 IF original REGEXP pattern THEN 
  loop_label: LOOP 
   IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN
    LEAVE loop_label;  
   END IF;
   SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,1);
   IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,ch);
   ELSE
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);
   END IF;
   SET i=i+1;
  END LOOP;
 ELSE
  SET temp = original;
 END IF;
 RETURN temp;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = regex_replace('<noindex>.*</noindex>', '', post_content);
```

The tested UPDATE command returns no results. Issues with the code are probably related to how the string to search for in regex_replace is not written correctly.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: wow, stored XSS! I would handle the problem with a better suited language for the task. You are doing it offline anyway, you could use better tools to make sure the task is effectively done and add controls and logging to asses the result.

Comment: I am running version 5.6.